# navigate to specific JSON node and use ObjectMapper

Tags: java, jackson

I want to use Jackson to navigate to a specific JSON and then send the values over the ObjectMapper.  I can currently achieve this if the JSON is just a simple array like this:

```
[
    {
        "parent": "A",
        "child": "B"
    },{
        "parent": "G",
        "child": "K"
    }
]
```

My Java code looks like this and it works.

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Row[] row;

row = mapper.readValue(json, Row[].class);
```

But when the JSON is a bit more nested like this:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "parent": "A",
            "child": "B"
        },{
            "parent": "G",
            "child": "K"
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm unsure what I need to do to achieve the same effect.

The `Row` class is just a standard class with the parent and child properties along with its getters and setters.  Nothing special there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first use `readTree()` to get a tree representation of the JSON string .Then use JSON pointer ([RFC-6901](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6901)) to navigate to the `JsonNode` that you want start to deserialise . After that,  use `treeToValue()` to deserialise the tree to `Row[]` :

```java
JsonNode rootNode = mapper.readTree(json);
JsonNode dataNode = rootNode.at("/data");
Row[] rows = mapper.treeToValue(dataNode, Row[].class);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a map. Where the data is a key in the map and the list of objects is the value. This your list [] is the values. Inside your list you have an object.In java...

```
     Map<String, List<Parents>> studentsParent = HashMap<>(); class Parent{ String parent; String child; parent(String parent, String child){
         this.parent = parent;
         this.child = child; } 
} List<Parents> parents = new ArrayList<>(); 
  studentsParent.put (data, Parents.add( Parent p = new Parent("A", "B"))); [
            {
                "parent": "A",
                "child": "B"
            },{
                "parent": "G",
                "child": "K"
            }
        ]
```